# Grails json-views seem to be getting ignored

Tags: json, rest, grails

I have Grails 4.0.5 restful-profile application working great in my dev env. I can access the defined URL's and adapt the output based on the json views I have generated.

When I start the war or jar using the embedded tomcat server this too seems to work well, as expected.

Now I want to deploy the war file to a separate Tomcat Server in prod and now it's as though the json views cannot be found. The main application screen gives a 500 error and when I access the URL's on my controllers the output is generated as though I had not supplied any json views.

I'm not sure what I have done wrong or if this is a defect? Has anyone else seen this before?

Comment: Do you see any exception in the logs? It could be similar to https://github.com/grails/grails-views/issues/140

Comment: Hi Puneet - yes this looks familiar to what I am seeing although if I understand correctly there are enough people who do not have this problem and therefore I wonder if I do not have a simple config error which is causing this. When I up the logging to debug in tomcat I do not see anything specific wrt views I had changed not being found - I do see a msg that the index and error templates are missing

Comment: Did you try to apply the suggestions from this issue to see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Hi Puneet - apologies for the delay and thanks for the nudge to have a look at this. I just followed the latter part of the link you sent me and added a similiar statement setting the templatePath to my resources.groovy file, deployed it to Tomcat and can confirm this worked! Many thanks for the link and helping me on this!!